# Как настроить прокси для uwsgi

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

пытаюсь постичь азы докера, нгинкс и пайтона, и видимо что-то упускаю и/или понимаю неверно.

все здесь:

https://github.com/dasauser/alpine-uwsgi-nginx-python-docker

бросает ошибку 502 и в логах нгинкса это:

```
2019/12/06 15:25:36 [error] 6#6: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: web, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:746", host: "localhost:747"
```

как правильно настроить эту связку?

Comment: Вот при старте выскакивает: `failed to open python file /var/www/web/public/index.py`. Нет в контейнере этого файла. Нужно монтировать через механизм volumes

Comment: Да, в репозитории нету, т.к. файл находится в другой директории и прекрасно монтируется. Извините, конечно, но создайте файл в такой директории сами и проверьте. Так же он будет доступен по при обращении к localhost:746/